# SQLite database is locked #2

Tags: c#, sqlite

I have 2 queries but on update `cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();` it throws an exception "database is locked":

```
if (txt_balance.Text != "")
{
    using ( SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(obj.getDbSourceFile))
    {
        con.Open();
        SQLiteCommand cmd1 = new SQLiteCommand("SELECT [supplier_balance] FROM [s_supplier] where supplier_name='" + comboPurchaseSupplier.Text + "'", con);
        SQLiteDataReader DR = cmd1.ExecuteReader();
        // hfcconn.Close();
        if (DR.HasRows)
        {
            if (DR.Read())
            {
                //hfcconn.Open();
                using (SQLiteConnection con2 = new SQLiteConnection(obj.getDbSourceFile))
                {
                    SQLiteCommand cmd2 = new SQLiteCommand("update [s_supplier] set supplier_balance=" + (DR.GetInt32(0) + Convert.ToInt32(txt_balance.Text)) + " where supplier_name='" + comboPurchaseSupplier.Text + "'", con2);

                    con2.Open();
                    cmd2.ExecuteNonQuery();


                    DR.Dispose();
                    // con.Close();
                }
            }
        }
     // con.Close();
     }
}
```

Comment: `it throw exception database is locked` Please include more exception details in your post - such as the type, message and stack trace of the exception.

Comment: The system offered you 1366 posts with titles very similar to yours.  Did you check any of them?  I'm too exhausted from fixing up the poorly formatted code, but that is not the correct way to create SQL - use SQL Parameters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using two connections.

Connections (and their transactions) are isolated from each other, so the second connection cannot update a table on which the first connection still has an open reader.

Comment: I had disposed the reader and using `using ( SQLiteConnection con = new SQLiteConnection(obj.getDbSourceFile))` which close the connection @CL.

Comment: But the second statement is executed before that happens.

Comment: I have an another update query on which i got exception db locked and it is in separate using clause @CL.